# What is wrong with this reasoning on topology?

Tags: general-topology

In the topology $\mathbb R_l $ on the real line $\mathbb R$ with $[a,  b)$ is the basis.

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [a \! - \! 1/n, \ b) = (a, b)$

Thus $(a,b) $ is an open set.

Thus $\mathbb R_l $ is same as the regular topology on the real line.

It seems this may affect some of the 'closed sets contain all the limit points' property. Or would it?

Comment: @quasi Oh.. $\mathbb R_l $ is the topology with base  $ [a,b) $ . Isn't that standard?

Comment: Just cause $(a,b)$ is an open set under $\mathbb R_l$ doesn't mean that $\mathbb R_l$ is the same as the standard topology... why would it? It just means it's finer.

Comment: If it were the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, then in fact the basis elements $[a,b)$ would be open in the usual topology. Are they?

Comment: The fact that you have found a set (the open interval $(a,b)$) which is open in both topologies does not mean they are the same. (With a little less work you could have found that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb R$ are open in both topologies; that doesn't make them the same topology either.) For the topologies to be the same, it's not enough that they have ***some*** open sets in common, ***all*** the open sets should be the same. Is the half-open interval $[0,1)$ open in the topology $\mathbb R_l$? Is it open in the regular topology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have shown that that an arbitrary open interval $(a,b)$ is open under the topology $\mathbb R_l$ which implies (because the open intervals are a basis for the standard topology) that $\mathbb R_l$ is a finer topology than the standard topology of the real line (i.e. it has *more* open sets). This doesn't mean it's the same topology. For instance, obviously $[a,b)$ is open under $\mathbb R_l$ but not under then standard topology. So it's a strictly finer topology.